# How to resolve the following dependencies for my Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, dependencies

I've been trying to deploy my Next.js app to Vercel and I seem to be getting the following errors when running npm install:

```
labber@Viacaelestis:~/route-roamer$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: openai-quickstart-node@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@13.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"^13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer next@">=2" from next-routes@1.4.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/next-routes
npm ERR!       next-routes@"^1.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.4.2 || ^16" from next-routes@1.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/next-routes
npm ERR!   next-routes@"^1.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/labber/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/labber/.npm/_logs/2023-04-30T02_47_32_135Z-debug-0.log
```

For context, during development, we were able to get the app to work simply by using --force for all the npm installs (which we knew was not ideal, but for the sake of time, we did so anyways - this was for a bootcamp final project).

I've tried a couple things like playing around with different versions of react-dates for example, but overall, I'm not sure what I'm doing or what's the best way to proceed. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

If it helps at all, here's the link to my Github repo for this project: https://github.com/michaelocenar/route-roamer